# How to reset $stateparam parameter value to null in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my code.

```
.state('appSetting.studentList', { url: '/student', views: { 'list@appSetting': { templateUrl: appUrl + '/Student/List', controller: 'StudentCtrl' } } })
                .state('appSetting.studentList.details', { url: '/:studentId', views: { 'details@appSetting': { templateUrl: appUrl + '/Student/Edit', controller: 'StudentEditCtrl' } } })

                .state('appSetting.employeeList', { url: '/employee', views: { 'list@appSetting': { templateUrl: appUrl + '/Employee/List', controller: 'EmployeeCtrl' } } })
                .state('appSetting.employeeList.details', { url: '/:employeeId', views: { 'details@appSetting': { templateUrl: appUrl + '/Employee/Edit', controller: 'EmployeeEditCtrl' } } })
```

I have a add button on layout , when user click the add button call the following function.

```
 $scope.gotoAdd = function () {
        if ($state.current.name.indexOf(".details") == -1) {
            $state.go($state.current.name + ".details")
        }
        else {
            var paramId = $state.current.url.slice(2);
            $state.go($state.current.name, ({ studentId: "", reload: true }));
        }
    };
```

In the above code working fine, but when open employee page user click add button i want to empty of employeeId parameter. I have number of links so if condition is using lengthy process. The above variable paramId dynamically changed (one time "studentId" , "employeeId" ,..............) depends on current state. 
I tried the following code but not working because paramId contains string value

```
 $state.go($state.current.name, ({ paramId: "", reload: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting the second parameter in '( )' in $state.go().

Try

$state.go($state.current.next, {}, {reload: true});

or

$state.go($state.current.next, {paramId: ""}, {reload: true});

Comment: I already tried that code but not working when i write paramId:"" but still studentId not empty

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.gotoAdd = function () {
        if ($state.current.name.indexOf(".details") == -1) {
            $state.go($state.current.name + ".details")
        }
        else {
            for (var prop in $stateParams) {
                if ($stateParams.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    $stateParams[prop] = '';
                }
            }
            $state.go($state.current.name,$stateParams, { reload: true });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

`$state.go` can take an `inherit` boolean parameter that serve exactly for this purpose.

As of UI router 0.2.15 -probably an old version, the documentation states

> **`inherit`** - {boolean=true}, If `true` will inherit url parameters from current url.

In fact, it reset not only url parameters, but all `$stateParams` to their default, like what they are in state definition.

This will keep only state params as passed through the `params` object and all other are set to default or deleted.

```
$state.go('target.state', params, {inherit: false});
```